# How can I configure jest to handle SvelteKit's `$lib` alias?

Tags: jestjs, sveltekit

When I try to run a test in jest that imports a file using the [`$lib` alias](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs#modules-$lib), `jest` fails to run with the error `Cannot find module '$lib/...'`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add the following to `jest.config.cjs`:

```
module.exports = {
  ...,
  moduleNameMapper: { '^\\$lib(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/lib$1' },
}
```

The documentation can be found under [Using with webpack](https://jestjs.io/docs/webpack#configuring-jest-to-find-our-files).